# Deploying Worklight on WebSphere

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

I've deployed Worklight 6 on WebSphere 8.5.5 trying to follow these instructions ( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp ) with a derby database and I've encountered the following error when trying to hit my Worklight instance:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
```

When I check the log, I can see that the worklight server has not been started due to this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
...
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.toOpenJPAProperties(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:499)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:317)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:160)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:62)
```

I put the worklight jar directly in the WebSphere lib to solve another problem related to an Authentication class not being found if I recall correctly... Perhaps I need more jars in there, or did I solve my previous problem incorrectly? I put the javax.peristence.jar inside websphere as well, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ant scripts for deployment? This happens if you miss some steps while doing the manual application deployment.